# RAW mars CTX raster processing

Tags: qgis, python, raster, gdal, geoprocessing

I am trying to download a raw CTX image from mars reconnaissance orbiter mission.
the following link is the API request I got data from

https://oderest.rsl.wustl.edu/live2/?query=product&r=omfc&proj=c0&target=mars&ihid=MRO&iid=CTX&pt=EDR&mincreationtime=2019-07-01&maxcreationtime=2023-7-01&order=obd&footprint=POLYGON%20((32.79%20-19.6151,%2033.4%20-23.7397,%2032.8%20-23.8092,%2032.2%20-19.6845,%2032.79%20-19.6151))

the product ID
<ode_id>28437764</ode_id>

image url
https://planetarydata.jpl.nasa.gov/img/data/mro/mars_reconnaissance_orbiter/ctx/mrox_3600/data/N02_063178_1581_XI_21S327W.IMG

After downloading I tried to georeference the raster to the given polygon in the request link.

There seems to be some misfit in the features between the given raster and any global mars map, where if i download the same image processed from other site
http://viewer.mars.asu.edu/planetview/inst/ctx/N02_063178_1581_XI_21S327W#P=N02_063178_1581_XI_21S327W&T=2

it fits.

What was the processing procedure done on the raster?